# IIRF with IIS and the ASP.Net Tilde (~) 

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iirf

When I turn on URL Rewriting to access a page, the ~ no long is replaced with the application root.

For example

```
<asp:image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/image.png"/>
```

should produce:

```
<img src="/testing/Images/image.png">
```

but its only outputting

```
<img src="/Images/image.png">
```

The tilde is supposed to be replaced with the application root path but it looks like IIRF is messing with that somehow?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The tilde (~) character represents the root directory of the application in ASP.NET. It is replaced with the appropriate value in ASP.Net server controls before sending the markup to the client.

IIRF on the other hand rewrites URL's before entering the ASP.Net pipe. It transforms requests coming from clients.

IIRF modifies *requests*, whereas ASP.Net transforms the tilde in the *response*.

Therefore, **in the markup sent to the client, you should never see a tilde.**

If you do have a tilde in the markup sent to the client, it is probably a bug and you should modify your code to have it replaced correctly.

Some pointers to make sure the tilde gets replaced:

- [Avoiding problems with relative and absolute URLs](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2004/05/05/avoiding-problems-with-relative-and-absolute-urls-in-asp-net.aspx)
- [ResolveUrl & master pages](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/code_blocks_inside_master_pages_cause_trouble.aspx)